# Center text on div when hover but inherited width and height

Tags: html, css, image, overlay, center

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/LW9DJ/1/

I want the overlay text to appear centered (which is currently working), but I don't want the css class 'mycell' to have the width or height attributes set, I want them inherited from 'container' class.

This is because I am going to implement this in a responsive website in which the width and height of 'container' class are automatically changed.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/o7iAFMu.jpg" class="test" />
    <div class="overlay">
            <div class="mycell">Some Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/LW9DJ/2/

Comment: Im sorry, the source code i passed to you was not ok, this is the corrected one: http://jsfiddle.net/7M5Wb/1/

Comment: Well, you could try to adapt the code provided, can't you?

Comment: I've been trying with your sources but i am unable to readapt it. I only have with and height in the <img> tag noy in the 'container' class.

Answer (score -1):

You should make left-margin and right-margin properties of style, auto. When you assign auto values to these two properties, the div would be located at the center.